# Inconsistent skewness results between basic skewness formula, Python and R

Tags: python, r, scipy, distribution

The data I'm using is pasted below. When I apply [the basic formula](http://study.com/academy/lesson/skewness-in-statistics-definition-formula-example.html) for skewness to my data in R:

```
3*(mean(data) - median(data))/sd(data)
```

The result is -0.07949198. I get a very similar result in Python. The median is therefore greater than the mean suggesting the left tail is longer.

However, when I apply the descdist function from the [fitdistrplus package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/fitdistrplus.pdf), the skewness is 0.3076471 suggesting the right tail is longer. The Scipy function [skew](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skew.html) again returns a skewness of 0.303.

Can I trust this simple formula which gives me a negative skewness? What is going on here.

Thanks,
Oliver

```
data = c(0.18941565600882029, 1.9861271676300578, -5.2022598870056491, 1.6826411075612353, 1.6826411075612353, -2.9502890173410403, -2.923253150057274, -2.9778296382730454, 0.71202396234488663, 0.71202396234488663, -3.1281373844121529, 1.8326831382748159, -5.2961554710604135, 2.7793190416141234, 0.46922759190417185, 7.0730158730158728, 1.1745152354570636, 2.8142292490118579, 2.037940379403794, 7.0607489597780866, 10.460258249641321, 11.894978479196554, 4.8334682860998655, 1.3884016973125886, 4.0940458015267174, 0.12592959841348539, -0.37022332506203476, 1.9713554987212274, -0.83774145616641893, -1.896978417266187, 6.4340675477239362, -6.4774193548387089, -0.31790393013100438, -4.4193265007320646, 5.7454545454545451, 2.5913432835820895, 0.86190724335591451, 0.95753781950965045, 6.8923556942277697, 1.7650659630606862, -2.4558421851289833, -2.390546528803545, 2.6355029585798815, 0.26983655274888557, 1.5032159264931086, 3.9839506172839503, -5.1404511278195484, -2.2477777777777779, 6.0604444444444443, -0.9691172451489477, 1.1383462670591382, -1.5281319661168078, 4.7775667118950702, 1.2223175965665234, 2.0563555555555553, -3.6153201970443352, -0.35731206188058978, -3.6265094676670238, 1.3053804930332262, -4.4604960677555958, -0.8933514246947083, 0.7622542595019659, 1.3892170651664322, 2.5725258493353031, -0.028006088280060883, 0.8933947772657449, 2.4907086614173228, 3.0914196567862717, 4.4222575516693157, 0.64568527918781726, 0.97095158597662778, -3.7409780775716697, -3.3472636815920396, -0.66307448494453247, -7.0384291725105186, -0.14540612516644474, -0.38161535029004906, 5.1076923076923082, 4.0237516869095806, 1.510099573257468, 1.5064083457526081, -0.025879043600562587, 4.5001414427156998, 3.2326264274061991, 1.0185639229422065, 2.66690518783542, 0.53032015065913374, 1.2117829457364342, 0.60861244019138749, -2.5248049921996878, 1.8666666666666669, -0.32978612415232139, 0.29055999999999998, 1.9150729335494328, 2.2988352745424296, 3.779225265235628, 0.093884800811976657, 1.0097869890616005, 1.2220632081097198, 0.21164401128494487)
```

Comment: You shouldn't believe everything you read on the Internet. I suspect skewness in R would be the third central moment rather than that definition you dug up. The code should be available. (My hunch is confirmed: `skewness <- function(data) {
            sd <- sqrt(moment(data, 2))
            return(moment(data, 3)/sd^3)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have access to the packages you mention right now so I can't check which formula they apply, however, you seem to be using Pearson's second skewness coefficient (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness)). The estimator for the sample skewness is given on the same page and is given by the third moment which can be calculated simply by:

```
> S <- mean((data-mean(data))^3)/sd(data)^3
> S
[1] 0.2984792
> n <- length(data)
> S_alt <- S*n^2/((n-1)*(n-2))
> S_alt
[1] 0.3076471
```

See the alternative definition on the wiki page which yields the same results as in your example.

Answer (score 2):

The skewness is generally defined as the third central moment (at least when it is being used by statisticians.) The Wikipedia skewness page explains why the definition you found is unreliable. (I had never seen that definition.) The code in `descdist` is easy to review:

```
moment <- function(data, k) {
        m1 <- mean(data)        # so this is a "central moment"
        return(sum((data - m1)^k)/length(data))
    }
skewness <- function(data) {
            sd <- sqrt(moment(data, 2))
            return(moment(data, 3)/sd^3)}
skewness(data)
#[1] 0.3030131
```

The version you use is apparently called 'median skewness' or 'non-parametric skewness'. See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159098/taming-of-the-skew-why-are-there-so-many-skew-functions